# typescript with systemjs configuration error

Tags: typescript, systemjs

i've followed this simple tutorial step by step but i got this 404 error 
[enter link description here](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/)

i'm sure i've installed typescript locally

```
npm install typescript --save
```

(the typescript in the node_modules folder is present)

this is the output of lite-server

```
17.05.18 09:14:25 200 GET /index.html
17.05.18 09:14:25 200 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js
17.05.18 09:14:25 200 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js.map
17.05.18 09:14:25 200 GET /node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
17.05.18 09:14:25 200 GET /src/main.ts
17.05.18 09:14:25 404 GET /typescript
```

and in the browser console

```
[object Error]{description: "Fetch error...", message: "Fetch error...", name: "Error", originalErr: Error {...}, stack: "Error: Fetc..."}
Instantiating http://localhost:3000/typescript
Loading typescript
Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts 
Instantiating http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts
```

how can i investigate further?

---

project structure:

```
.
├── index.html
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── main.ts
    └── person.ts
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SystemJS</title>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript',
        packages : {
            src: {
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            }
        }
    });
    System
      .import('src/main')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
import { Person } from './person';

let person = new Person();
console.log(person.name);
```

person.ts

```
export class Person {
    public name: string = 'xxxxxx';
}
```

Comment: can you post the full message in the error you get in the console?

Comment: please provide source code, its difficult to say something without seeing your code.

Comment: source code provided

Answer (score 1):

I followed the link you provided and created a working plunkr demo for you.

[Plunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/Z6JbWiHLHWYouAL8jQ1k/)

This is how my script in index.html looks. Hope this helps.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    packages: {
      src: {
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      }
    },
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    },
    map: {
      'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js'
    }
  });
  System
    .import('src/main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your plunker! adding "paths" and "map" properties to the SystemJS configuration my code works, and morover i noted the output of lite server doesn't show the 404 on the "/typescript" path. Does it mean that it is loading  typescript from remote? (a sort fo cdn?) or is loading from the node_modules folder. If it is true "the first" why the code in the tutorial works without the "paths" and "map" properties

Comment: In the tutorial typescript is referred from node_module folder which you can see in last `index.html` code sample. In my plunkr example its loaded via CDN (unpkg.com) which you can see in paths section.